# set an image just for background of the header page

Tags: header

I am a junior web designer. I have a problem. please help me... I'm trying to make a website and I want to set a background just for header not for all of the page.what should I do?

Comment: Just create a section inside the `body` named `header` or whatever and apply style to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
body {
display: inline-block;
background-image: url("http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00893/uhz63f8xhn0n.jpg"); 
} 
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<p>Ahmad</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It work for me , just put the url of the image like this :    


 background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg");

Comment: I know what you say and I put my photo's url...but it dos'nt work

Comment: Yes , you photo code that does not  your image in the background

Comment: it work Fine for me , Put all you code to see why it does not   work

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00893/uhz63f8xhn0n.jpg
f");
   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>

Comment: I update my answer , Try it , it work 100% you have to add http

Comment: it has http,I don't know why here is'nt